# Undo SQL UPDATE Azure DB

Tags: sql-server, update, azure-sql-database

I have accidentally updated over 3,000 records in one of my tables hosted on Azure. This was not a transaction and I did not have any back ups for this table.

I've read around and found ApexSQL Log but when I connect I try to connect I see "SQL server Azure is not supported"

I understand that this tool examines logs to reproduce the data, is there a manual technique to do is, or an alternative compatible tool?

I also found this [tutorial](http://raresql.com/2012/02/01/how-to-recover-modified-records-from-sql-server-part-1/) but after running it on Azure I see 'Invalid object name 'fn_dblog'

Really grateful for you support.

Thanks.

Comment: any backups of your data ? restore from there

Comment: don't suppose you have a backup you could restore elsewhere and evaluate the changes that way?

Comment: Have a look here maybe this will help [`Recover deleted data in SQL Server`](http://sqlbak.com/blog/recover-deleted-data-in-sql-server/)

Comment: No unfortunately I did not have a backup of the table...

Comment: What service tier are you using?  ie Web, Business, Basic, Standard or Premium.  This will determine if you have any options.

Comment: The db is currently set to "WEB" edition. Is there anything I can do with this tier?

Comment: Sadly not.  Web or Business edition only support manual database copy or export at this time and are due to be retired in 2015.  Did you take *any* kind of manual backup?  If so, you could re-deploy it as a different db name, extract the data eg with bcp, SSIS, and reload the table, basically effecting a table-level restore.  How did the data get there in the first place?

Comment: The data had been added through post requests from users. I've fortunately managed to recover 70% of the data from logs but that looks like the best I'm going to get. Always back up!

Answer (score 4):

> I have accidentally updated over 3,000 records in one of my tables hosted on Azure.

You are out of luck *(since you do not have any backups).*

Also, it is not possible to use the undocumented command `fn_dblog` in Azure. It is only supported in SQL Server.

Also Transaction logs are no longer managed by the DBA in SQL Azure; this is automatically managed by SQL Azure's infrastructure.

check out : [Supported Transact-SQL Statements (Azure SQL Database)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee336270.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Which edition of SQL Azure are you using?

If its one of the newer editions, you can make use of the Point In Time recovery

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj650016.aspx

Comment: Web edition (as the OP has) does not support point in time recovery.

Comment: @kin ah..  that info was added later. I'll still let this be here if anyone using the new editions stumbles on this question...

Answer (score 0):

ApexSQL Log doesn't support SQL Azure because the transaction log file is differently handled in SQL Azure, and cannot be physically read by a tool.

*I work in ApexSQL*